# If $X$ is compact then $X$ is sequentially compact.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

My attempt :

We assume that $X$ is a compact metric space and we let $A=(x_n)$ be a sequence. Then $A \subset G_1 \cup G_2.....G_k$.So suppose $G_i$ contains infinitely many points of $(x_n)$.We choose $y \in G_i$ in such a way so that  we can find a ball $B_d(y,\epsilon) $ such that it is contained in $G_i$ and it contains infinitely many points of $(x_n)$.Then let us say that the susbsequence $(x_{n_k})$ is contained in the ball. I am trying to show that the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $y$.

How do I go about from here? If someone could suggest a way out instead of suggesting a different answer.

Comment: Are you using covering compact as the definition of com[pact, with Gi being a finite subcover of X?

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach: suppose $(x_n)$ has no convergent subsequence. Then, for each integer $n$ there is an open neighborhood $U_i\ni x_i$ such that $U_i\cap U_j=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j.$ Furthermore, $C:=\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is closed because it has no limit points, hence has them all. Then $\mathscr U=\{C^c\}\cup \{U_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.

Answer (score 3):

You need to state explicitly that $X$ is a metric space, since the result is not true for topological spaces in general. The beginning of your argument makes no sense as stated: where do $G_1,\ldots,G_k$ come from, and what are they? We might **guess** that you started with some open cover of $X$ and took a finite subcover, but you need to say so. You also need to say something about the open cover with which you started. For all we know, you started with the cover $\{X\}$, so that $k=1$ and $G_1=X$.

Next, for a given $\epsilon$ how do you know that there is point $y\in G_i$ such that $B_d(y,\epsilon)\subseteq G_i$ and $B_d(y,\epsilon)$ contains infinitely terms of the sequence? This requires proof, which you have not given. Finally, it is simply not true that the subsequence in question necessarily converges to $y$.

At this point you don’t have enough of a proof for it to be salvageable. I strongly recommend that you try instead to prove the result by showing that if $X$ has a sequence with no convergent subsequence, then $X$ is not compact. A direct proof is possible, by showing that every sequence in $X$ has a Cauchy subsequence and then using the fact that compact metric spaces are complete, but that’s a bit harder.

Comment: I am very confused. I really couldn't understand why subsequence converges to a point in a closed set. But if that is true then why will the proof be wrong. Can you explain please..

Comment: @GuriaSona: You should completely ignore **Divide1918**’s answer: it is not at all helpful. In my answer I pointed out some of the serious flaws in your argument; you should begin by trying to understand them.

Comment: So can I be using the bolzano weistrass property?in   Every compact metric space an infinite set has a limit point so then we can conclude that $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $y$ which is a limit point

Comment: @GuriaSona: If you’ve proved it, you could use the Bolzano-Weierstrass property to conclude that if the **sequence** $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has infinitely many distinct points, then the **set** $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ has a limit point in $X$, but after that it still takes some work to show that the sequence has a subsequence converging to that limit point. And you also still have to deal with the case in which $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is not sequentially compact, then there is a sequence $(p_n)\subset X$ which admits no subsequence converging to a point in $X$. Then $\forall x\in X,\exists r\gt 0$ such that $p_j\in B_d(x,r)$ for only finitely many $j$. $\{{B_d(x,r)}:x\in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$, so by compactness it admits a finite subcover $\{B_d(x_i,r_i)\}_{i=1}^N$. Since $(p_n)$ have only finitely many terms in each $B_d(x_i,r_i)$, it follows that $(p_n)$ has only finitely many terms, a contradiction.

Comment: Combining this with what’s in the question does not yield a proof of the result.

Comment: In a closed set a subsequence always converges to a point?

Comment: This combined with what's in the question proves that every sequence in X admits a convergent subsequence converging to a point in X, which is the definition of sequentially compact.

Comment: @Divide1918: It proves nothing of the kind. The OP’s subsequence isn’t even guaranteed to be convergent, let alone convergent to $y$.

Comment: @GuriaSona: No; it need not converge at all. If the space is compact it will have a subsequence that converges to a point, but that’s what you’re trying to prove, so you can’t assume it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Isn't compactness of the space exactly the assumption?

Comment: @Divide1918: Yes, the space is compact. And yes, the sequence has a convergent subsequence, **but that’s what you’re trying to prove, so you can’t assume it in the course of the proof**.